# How can I prevent my Windows server from conducting port scans

Tags: windows-server-2008, port

I have several EC2 Windows servers on Amazon's AWS.  I have been receiving messages from Amazon that my servers are conducting port scans on remote hosts on the internet.  I have scanned the machines for viruses and malware using Malwarebytes and Trend Micro.  They come up clean.  How can I stop my servers from conducting these port scans.  As clarification, my servers are the attackers.

Comment: As a stop gap you could limit outbound traffic from the server.  This has some "unintended" consequences if you aren't careful, but it might bide some time to let you figure out what is causing the port scans.

Answer (score 2):

You should try to find out what process is performing these port scans

```
netstat -b -a
```

could give you an idea, but the [SysInternals tools](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897437) Tcpvcon and TCPView also give you the process id as well as the process name.

Then investigate that process further.

If the port scans don't happen all the time, you can schedule tcpvcon.exe to run every hour and pipe its output into a file.

Comment: Peter - Thanks for your response.  I loaded the TCPvcon and TCPView.  I see a number of active processes labeled only as [System Process] which are sporadically active on ports like 59221, 58952, 59225, 59230 etc.  How can I find out if these are the problem processes and exactly how to stop and eliminate it?

Comment: @Mark - The system process is special (It hosts all the kernel mode drivers) which makes it more complicated.  But it is normal that the System process listens on some ports. Check the Remote Address column in TCPView to see whether you recognize these hosts. In Process Explorer (also from SysInternals), review the threads of the system process. (process properties,  Threads tab) You may have to review all the drivers (*.sys) to find one that shouldn't be there. This is detective work, Google is your friend. Compare the threads to a clean server.